# SQL: Extract column headings from Dynamically Generated Table

Tags: mysql, sql

After selecting data from multiple tables, like this:

```
SELECT games.name, scores.score 
FROM games, scores
WHERE players.id = scores.player_id
```

..can I extract the column headings of this newly generated table?

The statement I'd normally use would be as follows:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name=table
```

But naturally this would not work for a dynamically generated table with no name

Help much appreciated!

Edit: I'm using the MariaDB client

Comment: `WHERE table_name IN ('games','scores') ORDER BY table_name, ordinal_position`

Comment: I don't think this is possible in sql, but it is possible in most mysql clients. But you didn't tell us what the client is.

Comment: Apologies. I'm using MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

> ..can I extract the column headings of this newly generated table?

No.  Mostly because you've not created a table.  Just a result set.  I think you already know this, because you've already looked at the information schema :)

Unfortunately it seems even creating a temporary table won't help - because those aren't stored in the information schema either.  I don't think you can declare cursors for `SHOW COLUMN...` statements either.

I don't think you've got a way to do it I'm afraid.

If it's a prepared statement (with the select statement held in a variable) you could probably chop it up using some ugly string manipulation...?

It might at this point be worth asking "more abstractly, what problem are you trying to solve?"